# Call SoapClient constructor with WSDL from a variable instead of a URL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Is it possible to call the PHP SoapClient constructor, which takes a URL as an argument, with the contents of a string instead.

In my example I have a manipulated DOMDocument containing WSDL which I would write into a string with saveXML().

The idea is to not touch the filesystem if possible. I have tried php://memory but tests on retrieving the stream content with functions like file_get_contents result in empty strings as I suspect the stream context has disappeared. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to instantiate the `SoapClient` class with a variable containing your `WSDL` string, all **without touching the filesystem**.  Since the `SoapClient` requires a URI parameter, we will create a [Data URI](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) and pass it in:

```
$wsdlstring  = <<<WSDL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions name="SoapArrayTest"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://test-uri/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  targetNamespace="http://test-uri/"
  >
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test-uri/">
      <complexType name="Baz">
        <sequence>
          <element name="fruit" type="tns:StringArray"/>
          <element name="vegetables" type="tns:StringArray"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="BazElement" type="tns:Baz"/>
      <complexType name="StringArray">
        <sequence>
          <element name="item" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="StringArrayElement" type="tns:StringArray"/>
    </schema>
  </types>
  <message name="fooRequest">
  </message>
  <message name="fooResponse">
    <part name="result" type="tns:Baz"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="TestPortType">
    <operation name="foo">
      <input message="tns:fooRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:fooResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding  name="TestBinding" type="tns:TestPortType">
    <soap:binding  style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation  name="foo">
      <soap:operation  soapAction="#foo" style="rpc"/>
      <input />
      <output >
        <soap:body  parts="result" use="literal" namespace="http://test-uri/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service  name="TestService">
    <port  name="TestPort" binding="tns:TestBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://example.com"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
WSDL;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($wsdlstring); 
$data = $doc->saveXML();
$wsdl = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($data);
$soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdl);
var_dump($soapclient->__getFunctions());
```

Comment: This just seems to cause an error when creating the SoapClient instance: "failed to open stream: rfc2397: no comma in URL"

Comment: I've expanded the answer to provide a working sample, however technically the WSDL now resides on the filesystem inside the PHP file itself.  However if the WSDL was constructed with just `DOMDocument` method calls, it would reside entirely in memory.  When I get a few moments of spare time, I will update the answer so the WSDL is constructed on-the-fly using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: I think key takeaway here is that, yes `SoapClient` can take a URL as an argument, but it's possible to pass in the contents of a string as the question asks, because PHP treats it like a stream context.  So we can substitute in `data://` instead of `file://` or `http://`